# Does Office Starter include the DLLs for Microsoft.Office.Interop?

Tags: ms-office, office-interop

I want to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to pull some data out of an XLS file.  I have Visual Studio 2010 and the Office Developer Tools installed.  However, I am getting a COMException error at `var app = new Application();` when the program runs.

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I have Office Starter 2010 installed.  Is it the case that I can't use the Interop libraries unless I have the full version of office?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Microsoft Office Starter 2010 cannot run Office solutions that you
>   create by using Visual Studio 2010.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608617.aspx

So I'd say the answer to your questions is yes. Now I realise you probably solved it already.
But just in case anyone else runs into this issue. :-)